# C# Crystal report me pide iniciar sesión SQL en el pc del cliente

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, crystal-reports

Tengo un problema con crystal reports para visual studio.

Tengo varios reportes hechos y en la maquina donde me encuentro desarrollando el sistema puedo visualizarlo sin problemas, pero al probar la aplicación en el pc del cliente me pide iniciar sesión en SQL, sin embargo, al ingresar las credenciales me muestra el mensaje de "No fue posible realizar la conexión"

[image: Inicio de sesión SQL]

[image: Error en la conexión]

He intentado varias cosas en el reportViewer:

1. Ingresar el nombre de usuario y contraseña antes y después de setear los parámetros

   `reporte.SetDatabaseLogon(user, password);`
2. Ingresar las credenciales y los valores del servidor:

   `reporte.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(server, database, user, password);`
3. Ingresar los datos de conexión a cada tabla

```
            ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo()
            {
                ServerName = server,
                DatabaseName = database,
                UserID = user,
                Password = password,
                Type = ConnectionInfoType.Query, //Use como tipo de conexión SQL y Query
                IntegratedSecurity = false
            };

            Tables T = reporte.Database.Tables;
            foreach(Table Tab in T)
            {
                TableLogOnInfo myt = Tab.LogOnInfo;
                myt.ConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo()
                {
                    ServerName = server,
                    DatabaseName = database,
                    UserID = user,
                    Password = password,
                    Type = ConnectionInfoType.Query,
                    IntegratedSecurity = false
                };

                Tab.ApplyLogOnInfo(myt);

            }
```

4. todas las configuraciones anteriores juntas y sigue sin funcionar

¿Qué debo hacer para visualizar los reportes sin problemas?

Estoy trabajando con Windows Form en visual studio 2019, SQL Server 2008 R2 y Crystal report para Microsoft visual studio 13.0.34.4636. Para la consulta utilizo un procedimiento almacenado conectándome al servidor a través de un OLE DB y la aplicación la genero a través de ClickOnce.

El equipo de cliente tiene crystal report runtime 13.0.34.4636 para 32 y 64 bit

Muchas gracias de antemano.